# Troubles with cron job cer.,pem

Tags: php, cron, jobs, pem

Hi im having a problem with a cron job with a php script, the answer the cron job is giving me is: "file cer.pem doesn't exists" however the file is in the same folder that the cron.php file im calling the file with the next code:

```
$params = array(
        "cadenaOriginal" => "cadenaOriginal.txt",
        "archivoKeyPem" => "key.pem",
        "archivoCerPem" => "cer.pem" 
    );
    try {
        $result = Sellar::ObtenerSello($params);
        return $result;
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo 'Caught exception: ', $e->getMessage(), "\n";
    }
```

but im getting the mentioned error this is the "ObtenerSello" funtion:

```
public static function ObtenerSello($params) {
        self::_checkOpenssl();
        if(isset($params['cadenaOriginal']) && isset($params['archivoCerPem']) && isset($params['archivoKeyPem'])){
            $cadena_original = $params['cadenaOriginal'];
            $archivoCerPem = $params['archivoCerPem'];
            $archivoKeyPem = $params['archivoKeyPem'];
        }else{
            throw new Exception('Se debe especificar una cadena original, archivo .cer.pem, archivo .key.pem');
        }
        self::_existsFile($cadena_original);
        self::_existsFile($archivoCerPem);
        self::_existsFile($archivoKeyPem);
        $cadena_original = file_get_contents($cadena_original);
        $pkeyid = openssl_get_privatekey(file_get_contents($archivoKeyPem));
        openssl_sign($cadena_original, $crypttext, $pkeyid, OPENSSL_ALGO_SHA256);
        openssl_free_key($pkeyid);
        $sello = base64_encode($crypttext);

        if(!self::_verifySeal($cadena_original, $crypttext, $archivoCerPem)){
            throw new Exception('Ocurrió un error al generar el sello.');
        }

        $r = ["status"=>"success", "sello"=>$sello];
        return json_encode($r);
    }`private static function _existsFile($file){
        if(!file_exists($file)){
            throw new Exception("El archivo $file no existe");
        }
    }`
```

all the files with this functions are in the same folder than cron.php but i keep getting the same error i already tried to put the path "../cron/cer.pem" but it says that "file ../cron/cer.pem doesn't exists" 
what am i doing wrong??
Thanks!!

Comment: Relative file paths almost always go wrong in cron.

Comment: so how can i fix it?

Comment: full file path for every file. Lot of times, you run it from the command line and your system path variables save you. Won't work in cron unless you re-specify all the path stuff there.

Comment: im using hostinger cron service so should i put the path like this?:
../home/user/public_html/pruebas/cron/cer.pem